# Initialize object member with reference in initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Am I doing this right? This is a highly simplified version of my code:

```
class Logger {
   public:
      Logger(std::ostream) { /*...*/}
};

class Driver {
public:
   Driver() : m_logger(std::cout) {}
   Driver(Logger& logger) : m_logger(logger) {}
private
   Logger m_logger;
};
```

So my class `Driver` has a member of type `Logger`. When I call the argument-less constructor `Driver()`, the instance of `Driver` creates its own instance of `Logger` using `std::cout`.

When calling `Driver(Logger)` the instance shall use an already existing instance of `Logger` passed as a reference.

The above code compiles using g++. Although I understand what happens when calling `Driver()`, I don't get what happens when calling `Driver(Logger)`. `Logger` has no constructor which accepts a reference on `Logger` as argument ("copy constructor"). So what is executed when calling `Driver(Logger)`?

Comment: You yourself provided a constructor for `Driver` to receive a `Logger` reference: `Driver(Logger& logger)`, And this is the standard and usual way of initializing reference members.I don't understand the Question.

Comment: You don't "call" constructors. Ever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Of course I do. `Driver* driver = new Driver()`.

Comment: @MBober: That is not a function call. I know it looks a bit like one, but it is not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A trivial copy constructor for `Logger` is synthesised for you**, unless you declare one yourself.

This is much the same as how a trivial default constructor is synthesised for you (if you don't declare a *default user-defined constructor*).

---

> `[C++11: 12.8/7]:` **If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly.** If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor
>   is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor. Thus, for the class definition
>
> ```
> struct X {
>    X(const X&, int);
> };
> ```
>
> a copy constructor is implicitly-declared. If the user-declared constructor is later defined as
>
> ```
> X::X(const X& x, int i =0) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> then any use of `X`’s copy constructor is ill-formed because of the ambiguity; no diagnostic is required.

> `[C++11: 12.8/8]:` The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class `X` will have the form
>
> ```
> X::X(const X&)
> ```
>
> if
>
> - each direct or virtual base class `B` of `X` has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type `const B&` or `const volatile B&`, and
> - for all the non-static data members of `X` that are of a class type `M` (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type `const M&` or `const volatile M&`.
>
> Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy constructor will have the form
>
> ```
> X::X(X&)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

When you construct a `Driver` with a `Logger` argument, it is taken by reference and the `Logger` copy constructor is invoked to initialize `m_logger`, so you end up with a new `Logger` that is a copy of the argument. The copy constructor is provided by the compiler unless you explicitly make `Logger` non-copyable, by declaring the copy constructor `private`.

Seems perfectly valid, except that you should make the `logger` argument a `const` reference; you're going to copy it, after all, not modify it.

Comment: What copy constructor? I have not defined a copy constructor for `Logger`. Or is this done implicitly?

Comment: @MBober: the compiler insert a default copy constructor if you don't define one explicitly.